# CREATE and DROP TABLESPACE Oracle

Tags: oracle, tablespace

I have created this tablespace

```
CREATE TABLESPACE IA643_TBS
DATAFILE 'IA643_dat' SIZE 500K
AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 300K MAXSIZE 100M;
```

I tried to drop it using this command

```
DROP TABLESPACE IA643_TBS;
```

And it said that it was dropped, when I tried to create it again, I got those error messages:

```
ERROR at line 1: 
ORA-01119: error in creating database file 'IA643_dat' 
ORA-27038: created file already exists 
OSD-04010: <create> option specified, file already exists
```

How can I delete the datafile and recreate the tablespace with same file names?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can either login to the operating system and actually delete the file or add the `reuse` keyword after the size in your `create tablespace` command.

Answer (score 1):

Answer of @Allan correct but for more clarity, let me show my example

```
SQL> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLESPACE tbs_temp_01 
 2    TEMPFILE 'tbs_temp_01.dbf'
 3    SIZE 5M reuse
 4    AUTOEXTEND ON;
```

[image]