# Oracle Database Error: ORA-01119 signaled during creating tablespace

Tags: oracle, partitioning, oracle12c, tablespace

I'm running an Oracle Database 12c Release 1 (12.1.0.2.0) on a Linux machine. To give some context to the situation, I've performed a partition for the database and am now trying to create a tablespace.

It doesn't go through and when I check my logs I see

```
CREATE TABLESPACE wlpspprim DATAFILE '/wlpspprim/wlpspprim.tbl' SIZE 25M AUTOEXTEND ON...
ORA-1119 signalled during: CREATE TABLESPACE wlpspprim DATAFILE '/wlpspprim/wlpspprim.tbl' SIZE 25M AUTOEXTEND ON...
```

I've double checked the disk space and I have more than enough space on the partitioned disk. Also I've made sure that the directory '/wlpspprim' does in fact exist on the machine - if anyone has any suggestions that would help a lot.

Thanks!

EDIT: Formatting

Comment: Are you trying to create a file with double quotes in the name?  Does that normally work on your system?

Comment: Sorry, I should've clarified this in my question - the "databasename" keyword is just the name of the database that I've created.

Comment: Have you checked if there's a directory named "databasename" anywhere in your file system, also?

Comment: Sorry I've realized that some parts of the question were unclear - I've replaced the keyword "databasename" with the actual values.

Comment: I think, you are using ASM database, aren't you?

Comment: No, I've just checked and it doesn't seem to the case - not using ASM

Comment: maybe your problem is : "adding a new datafile on primary and both primary and standby are in different file name directory, SQL APPLY from production database to Logical Standby database will fail with ORA-01119", true?

Comment: Are there any more error messages? It seems ORA-01119 is normally followed by other messages indicating space or permissions issues etc. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26536948/create-and-drop-tablespace-oracle

Comment: Hmmm the only error that I'm getting is ORA-1119